# Different results for re.compile().match on win10 and ubuntu with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, windows

I've got some strange behavior for win10 and ubuntu 18.04 with python 3.7.4 and next code

```
def tokenize(text, match=re.compile(b"([idel])|(\d+):|(-?\d+)").match):
    i = 0
    while i < len(text):
        m = match(text, i)
        s = m.group(m.lastindex)
        i = m.end()
        if m.lastindex == 2:
            yield "s"
            yield text[i:i + int(s)]
            i = i + int(s)
        else:
            yield s
```

When I open the file in rb mode on win10 and ubuntu I've got different results for

```
        m = match(text, i)
        s = m.group(m.lastindex)
```

For linux m.lastindex equals `1` but on win10 is `2`. Dumps for re.compile are equal, python's versions too.

On windows re.Match object has next values

```
<re.Match object; span=(1, 3), match=b'8:'>
```

On ubuntu:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match=b'8:'>
```

I've checked up python sources for match function it looks clean from #defines and other settings.
Did you faced a similar problem, how did you solve this? Thanks in advance. :)

P.S. Tested with any torrent file opened in rb mode. (e.g. http://releases.ubuntu.com/19.04/ubuntu-19.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)

P.P.S. I hadn't this issue with python 2. Seems it can be related with `newline types`, but file opened in rb mode.

**UPD:**
Made workaround with setting for `i = -1` for windows mode. Seems problem was with first byte. But could you please explain why this happens?

Comment: Actually I didn't reproduce your result. For Linux: `<re.Match object; span=(1, 3), match=b'8:'>`, for windows: `<re.Match object; span=(1, 3), match=b'8:'>`

Comment: Ok. I'm admit that my environment can be broken. I've run this code snippet in docker container `python:3.7.4-buster`, and got `<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match=b'd'>`.Something strange.

Comment: Reproduced on 32 and 64 python versions.

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned it seems it's related to newline types.

Try adding `newline=''` in the call to `open()` function when you open your file, this should enable universal newlines mode.

Comment: ```with open(local_torrent, "rb", newline='') as binary_file: ValueError: binary mode doesn't take a newline argument```  Unfortunately I need open it in binary mode.